# javascript autosum

Tags: javascript

Hi I am doing autosum in javascript which is working fine here in this link http://maatren.com/auto-sum.html but I want reverse autosum also.

Both are working fine but seperately. they are not working fine together.

I use this code

```
 function startCalc(){
      interval = setInterval("calc()",1);
    }
    function calc(){
      one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
      two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value; 
  third = document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value; 
      document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value = (one * 1) + ((two / 100) * one);
  //document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value = (third * 1) - ((two / 100) * third);
}
function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

My html is

```
<div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
    <form name="autoSumForm">
        <input class="right" type=text name="firstBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
        % <input class="right" type=text name="secondBox" value="10" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
        = <input class="right" type=text name="thirdBox" value="" onFocus="startCalc();" onBlur="stopCalc();"><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i remove comment from third box then it tops working. I want autosum and reverse autosum both at same time.

Comment: You should accept some answers to the questions you have posed before moving on to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
    <form name="autoSumForm">
        <input class="right" type=text name="firstBox" value="" onkeyup="calc(1);"><br>
        % <input class="right" type=text name="secondBox" value="10" onkeyup="calc(2);"><br>
        = <input class="right" type=text name="thirdBox" value="" onkeyup="calc(3);"><br>
    </form>
</div>
​
```

.

```
function calc(box){
  one = document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value;
  two = document.autoSumForm.secondBox.value; 
  third = document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value; 

  if(box == 1){
      document.autoSumForm.thirdBox.value = (one * 1) + ((two / 100) * one);;
  }else if(box == 2 || box == 3){
      document.autoSumForm.firstBox.value = (third * 1) - ((two / 100) * third);
  }

}
```